# Write functions resilient to variable dimension array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm struggling when writing a function that would seemlessly apply to any numpy arrays whatever its dimension.

At one point in my code, I have boolean arrays that I consider as mask for other arrays (0 = not passing, 1 = passing).
I would like to "enlarge" those mask arrays by overriding zeros adjacent to ones on a defined range.

Example :

```
input =         [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]
enlarged_by_1 = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0]
enlarged_by_2 = [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]


input =         [[0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0],
                 [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]]
enlarged_by_1 = [[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                 [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1]]
```

This is pretty straighforward when inputs are 1D.
However, I would like this function to take seemlessy 1D, matrix, 3D, and so on.
So for a matrix, the same logic would be applied to each lines.

I read about ellipsis, but it does not seem to be applicable in my case.
Flattening the input applying the logic and reshaping the array would lead to possible contamination between individual arrays.

I do not want to go through testing the shape of input numpy array / recursive function as it does not seems very clean to me.

Would you have some suggestions ?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). The Boolean masks are a means to some end, but the rest of us don't know what the end is, or if the masks would be the best way to even achieve that end.

Comment: The last dimension of my arrays are a physical quantity. I "observe" phenomenon rated along this physical quantity (1=presence, 0= nothing). along time. I want to confirm along time the presence of such phenomenon. Hence I "confirm" said presence by taking the product of my masks along the time dimension (masks corresponding to different time samples). However, there might be some drift along said physical quantity, hence my need to enlarge my mask in order to be robust to those drifts

Comment: Didn't think that was relevant here. Sorry.

Comment: It would help if you made it clear what the results should actually look like in multiple dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

The operation that you are described seems very much like a convolution operation followed by clipping to ensure that values remain 0 or 1.

For your example input:

```
import numpy as np

input = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0], dtype=int)
print(input)

def enlarge_ones(x, k):
    mask = np.ones(2*k+1, dtype=int)
    return np.clip(np.convolve(x, mask, mode='same'), 0, 1).astype(int)

print(enlarge_ones(input, k=1))
print(enlarge_ones(input, k=3))
```

which yields

```
[0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0]
[0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
```

`numpy.convolve` only works for 1-d arrays. However, one can imagine a `for` loop over the number of array dimensions and another `for` loop over each array. In other words, for a 2-d matrix first operate on every row and then on every column. You get the idea for nd-array with more dimensions. In other words the `enlarge_ones` would become something like:

```
def enlarge_ones(x, k):
    n = len(x.shape)
    if n == 1:
        mask = np.ones(2*k+1, dtype=int)
        return np.clip(np.convolve(x, mask, mode='same')[:len(x)], 0, 1).astype(int)
    else:
        x = x.copy()
        for d in range(n):
            for i in np.ndindex(x.shape[:-1]):
                x[i] = enlarge_ones(x[i], k)  # x[i] is 1-d
            x = x.transpose(list(range(1, n)) + [0])
        return x
```

Note the use of `np.transpose` to rotate the dimensions so that `np.convolve` is applied to the 1-d along each dimension. This is exactly `n` times, which returns the matrix to original shape at the end.

```
x = np.zeros((3, 5, 7), dtype=int)
x[1, 2, 2] = 1
print(x)
print(enlarge_ones(x, k=1))
```

```
[[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]]
[[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 1 1 1 0 0 0]
  [0 1 1 1 0 0 0]
  [0 1 1 1 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 1 1 1 0 0 0]
  [0 1 1 1 0 0 0]
  [0 1 1 1 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 1 1 1 0 0 0]
  [0 1 1 1 0 0 0]
  [0 1 1 1 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]]
```

Comment: I did'nt think about convolution thanks for the tip. However, that does not solve my issue, which is : how to make it resilent to variable dimension inputs : 1D, 2D, 3D at least. The solution you are proposing to extend the behavior to more than 1D consist of testing the dimension (if 2D then apply on each line, if 3D then apply on each element of last dimension). I thought there would be a cleaner solution to do it. f=For the moment that's what I do, even thought I find it ugly.

Comment: You misunderstood my last comment; you need to apply the convolution along each dimension! See the edited  answer.
I also added workaround a bug with `np.convolve` which would returns the wrong size when `x` has even length.